# Error:Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;initial catalog=newmits;trusted_connection=true");
cn.Open();
string a = string.Format("select * from upnotice where show like '{0}' ,%t");
SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(a, cn);
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet(); 
adp1.Fill(ds1);
GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I try without where condition it works but with where it does not work pls help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume this

```
string a = string.Format("select * from upnotice where show like '{0}' ,%t");
```

should be

```
string a = string.Format("select * from upnotice where show like '{0}'","%t");
```

Every format item(e.g. `{0}` or `{1}`) needs to have a corresponding argument.

However, you should not use `string.Format` but sql-parameters to [prevent sql-injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492403/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ADO-NET).